# Perl: Call a Subroutine Every 15 Seconds

Tags: perl, sleep, alarm, die

So I've been doing some looking around on here as well as on perl.org and perlmaven.com, but I'm confused with what's happening with the code that I'm trying to run. I've googled what $SIG is and found something on [here](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-capture-and-save-warnings-in-perl) that gives me a bit of an idea of what *local $SIG* is but I'm still confused by what he meant by this:

> Perl has a built-in hash called %SIG, in which the keys are the names of the signals available in you operating system. The values are subroutines (more specifically references to subroutines), that will be called when the specific signal arrives.
>
> In addition to the standard signals of your operating system Perl added two internal "signals". One of them is called **WARN** and is triggered every time some code calls the warn() function. The other one is called **DIE** and it is triggered when die() is called.

It also says on [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) that I shouldn't mix sleep calls within an alarm call, but what's explained on there seems like another language to me. **I'm confused. I'm having trouble getting out of the subroutine without it dying on me.** The code that I'm running is this (I obtained it from another post on here but I don't want to revive that post as it is from 2011):

```
sub checkfind {
didfindchange;
    while ($call_counter <= 20) {
        my $previous_call_finished = 0;
        eval {
            local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Alarm.\n" };
            alarm 15;
            if ($did_find_change eq "false") {
                didfindchange;
                print("Original FIND value: $original_find_value\n");
                print("FIND value: $ems_find_value\n");
            }
            elsif ($did_find_change eq "true") {
                print("FIND changed.\n");
                print("Original FIND value: $original_find_value\n");
                print("FIND value: $ems_find_value\n");
                $previous_call_finished = 1;
            }
            sleep;
        };
        #Propagate unexpected errors.
        die unless $@ eq "Alarm.\n";
        warn "Timed out!\n" unless $previous_call_finished
    }
    return;
}
```

My program just keeps dying and I'm unsure of the reason why. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: why are you sleeping?  for that matter, describe in English what you are trying to do

Comment: I want to call didfindchange() every 15 seconds. If FIND value changes, exit subroutine. If FIND value does not change, exit subroutine after five minutes has elapsed. I'm calling sleep() because for some reason the subroutine just dies if I don't. @ysth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, one would use an alarm for subroutines / external processes which can take a long time (waiting for db connection, network resource, really computationally expensive calculation, etc.).  You have to reset the alarm every time after the task finishes `alarm(0);`  For what I understand that you are trying to do, a simple sleep / timeout loop like the following should work for you.  For something more sophisticated (waiting for file events, network events), you may wish to consider programming with the EV event loops [perldoc EV](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/EV-4.21/EV.pm) or the AnyEvent library [perldoc AnyEvent](http://hhttp://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.11/lib/AnyEvent.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use constant TIMEOUT => 10;
use constant SLEEP   => 2;

check_for_something();
exit 0; # Success

sub check_for_something {
    my $start_time = time();
    my $elapsed = 0;
    while ( $elapsed < TIMEOUT ) {
        print "$elapsed seconds have elapsed...";
        my $value = look_for_something();
        print "Value is " . ( $value ? 'true' : 'false' ) . "\n";
        if ($value) {
            print "Value is true...returning\n";
            return "value has changed...";
        }

        sleep SLEEP;
        $elapsed = time() - $start_time;
    }
    die "Timed out after " . TIMEOUT . " seconds!\n";
}

sub look_for_something {
    # !! changes the number into either '1' or 'undef'
    # ! !! inverts the sense
    return ! !! int rand (2 * TIMEOUT / SLEEP); # False most of the time, occasionaly true     
}
```

**Output**

```
perl test_find.pl
0 seconds have elapsed...Value is false
2 seconds have elapsed...Value is false
4 seconds have elapsed...Value is false
6 seconds have elapsed...Value is false
8 seconds have elapsed...Value is false
Timed out after 10 seconds!

perl test_find.pl
0 seconds have elapsed...Value is false
2 seconds have elapsed...Value is false
4 seconds have elapsed...Value is true
Value is true...returning
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it seems that you're right and that I didn't have to use alarms. There were several things in your answer that intrigued me, however. Why do you use ($start_time) instead of $star_time (without the parentheses)? When you print what $value is does ($value ? 'true' : 'false' ) restrict what $value can be to only true or false? Why do you have two check_for_something() subroutines and an exit 0; right under one? And can you explain the look_for_something()'s return statement? I'm puzzled by the exclamation points.

Either way, thank you for your response. @xxfelixxx

Comment: The parentheses around `($start_time)` were unnecessary, so I have removed them.  They came from a habit of trying to avoid list-vs-scalar context bugs.  `$value` is set to either `1` or `undef`, so I convert it to the string 'true' or 'false' via the ternary operator.   The first `check_for_something()` is calling the subroutine which is defined later.  The `exit 0` is so that you can reason about the flow of the code (just because you `can` intersperse code and subroutines, does not mean it is nice to the next programmer...

Comment: As for the `!!` and `!!!`, although I would discourage such constructs in any real (production) code, they are part of perl's lore of `secret` operators: http://search.cpan.org/~book/perlsecret-1.013/lib/perlsecret.pod